# Implicit Route Model Binding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

Laravel's implicit route model binding isn't working. It is not looking up the record indicated by the identifier. I'm getting a brand new model object.

Given this code:

```
Route::get('users/{user}', function (App\User $user, $id) {
    $user2 = $user->find($id);
    return [
        [get_class($user), $user->exists, $user],
        [get_class($user2), $user2->exists],
    ];
});
```

And this URL: `/users/1`

I get this output:

```
[["App\\User",false,[]],["App\\User",true]]
```

I'm on PHP 7.2 and Laravel 5.6.

---

**Additional Information**

I've successfully accomplished implicit route model binding in other Laravel projects. I'm working on an existing codebase. As far as I can tell, the feature hasn't been used previously.

The user record exists. It has not been soft deleted. The model does not use the `SoftDeletes` trait.

I've tried this using various unique route names and other models.

I've checked the `App\Http\Kernel` class for the usual culprits. `$middlewareGroups` has `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,` in the `web` section and `$routeMiddleware` contains `'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,`.

Comment: Are there any customizations done to model? column aliases, behaviours, etc.

Comment: The user actually exists. I started on this trek with a resource controller and a different model entirely. What you see above my attempt to provide a [MCVE]. It tells me there's something in Laravel that isn't configured correctly.

Comment: just sounds like `SubstituteBindings` isn't running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue. The routes in `routes/web.php` did not have the `web` middleware. This is normally done in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` in the `mapWebRoutes()` function. At some point, during a Laravel upgrade, the route definition got mangled. It looked like this:

```
        Route::group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });
```

It could have been updated, using that older definition style, to look like this:

```
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });
```

Instead, I just copied the [latest method chaining style](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/2a1f3761e89df690190e9f50a6b4ac5ebb8b35a3/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L54) from the [`laravel/laravel`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) project, so it now looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

It should work without any problem in Laravel. I've just verified it in my Laravel 5.6 app and there is no problem with this.

Possible scenarios why are you getting this:

- user is soft deleted
- this route is not inside `web.php` or `api.php` file - the both groups have set `bindings` (or `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class`) inside `$midddlewareGroups` property in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file
- you removed mentioned bindings from one of those groups
- you have set some custom binding. For example if you defined somewhere code like this:
    
    `Route::bind('user', function($user) {
        return new \App\User();
    });`

  then you would get result as you showed because you use custom logic and just return empty user model.

If you think all above are false, I would start with fresh Laravel 5.6 application to try to replicate the issue.

Comment: I've updated my question to address your points, but I may have missed something.

Comment: @Sonny Maybe you should try verify what query is really run? You could try with my https://github.com/mnabialek/laravel-sql-logger package or  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to see if query is really running and how it looks like. Are you 100% sure you are using the same database you are checking the data?

Comment: I don't think the query is run. The middleware must be short-circuited somehow. I'm completely lost. I updated my post again to show that the record is easily loaded.

Comment: @Sonny Really hard to say anything more with the info you provided. As I said you should try to use some db logger to see if query is loaded. Maybe something more is added to the query, maybe you have some custom bindings, really hard to say more without seeing the whole app code.